# How to change system's statusbar color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have problem can't change status bar color in flutter, please help me...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWZgr.jpg)

Thank You:)

Answer (score 0):

Use SystemChrome to change or remove color of statusBar and also you can do more with it

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.purple,
  ));
```